# Rails5 ActionCable include current_user method from SessionsHelper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I want to get access to my **current_user** method which is defined in the **SessionsHelper**. How can I **include** or require it for the **ApplicationCable** Connection class?

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      if current_user
        self.current_user = current_user  
        logger.add_tags current_user.name
      end
    end
  end
end
```

gives me

```
There was an exception - NoMethodError(undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass)
```

Equivalent to the ApplicationController I **included** the SessionHelper in channels/application_cable/connection.rb

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    include SessionsHelper
    identified_by :current_user
    # (..)
  end
end
```

but doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in the [notes](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/actioncable#notes)of the official documentation the cable can not access the session. In [this](http://www.rubytutorial.io/actioncable-devise-authentication/) article, cited in the notes, you can find a way to use cookies for managing athentication